# no results when zero is an operand in calculator program

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm writing a calculator program using C

```
/*
 * sum.c
ch 2
1.Write a program in “SUM.C” which reads two integers and prints out the sum,
the difference and the product. Divide them too, printing your answer to two
decimal places. Also print the remainder after the two numbers are divided.
Introduce a test to ensure that when dividing the numbers, the second number
is not zero.
What happens when you add two numbers and the sum is too large to fit into
the data type you are using? Are there friendly error messages?

 *
 *  Created on: Jan 10, 2014
 *      Author: salahuddin
 */


#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int first,second;

    printf("Please enter two number a,b");
    scanf("%i,%i",&first,&second);

    printf("sum=%i,   difference=%i,   product=%i,    ",
            first+second,first-second,first*second);

    if(second!=0)
        printf("division=%.2lf,    ",(double)first/(double)second);
    else
        printf("remainder=%i",first%second);

return 0;
}
```

it works pretty well when entering numbers except 0 
when I entered 2,0 as the input, no thing appears

I've tried to debug it using the debugger in eclipse, the two variables get the values 2,0
but it doesn't print the result of the calculation and directly get out of the program?

can any one tell where the problem is?

Comment: @A4L - OP talks about 2 numbers here, not about one floating point number.

Comment: You need to take care of *all* the NaN cases e.g. 1/0 1%0 etc.

Comment: I entered 2,0 as the two inputs must be separated by ,

Comment: @OliCharlesworth where is 2 % 0?

Comment: @Salahuddin Here: `first%second`

Comment: Yeah, I got it, I should have included the first%second in the if statement because the problem appears when first % 0
Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1):

`2%0` is undefined behavior.

This will give you reminder after dividing by Zero. Dividing by Zero is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is probably being terminated due to doing division by zero. If you had more linefeeds and/or flush calls, you would probably see the output up until when the program dies.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
if(second!=0)
{
  printf("division=%.2lf,    ",(double)first/second);
  printf("remainder=%i",first%second);
}
```

try also to avoid using `scanf()` and instead read user input with
`fgets()` and then use `sscanf()` or `strtok(), atoi()` to retrieve contents.
`scanf()` can be a bit complicated to use and it is easy to do mistakes with.

Answer (score 0):

[`Floating point exception`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/doc/genprogc/floating-point_except.htm) due to division by zero.

You said you tried with debugger but you didn't mention the debugger error.

`gdb` gives bellow error

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x08048516 in main () at test.c:16
   16           printf("remainder=%i",first%second);
```